# XML string parsing in Java

Tags: java, xml, string

I am trying to parse through a XML format String for example;

```
<params  city="SANTA ANA" dateOfBirth="1970-01-01"/>
```

My goal is to add attributes name in an array list such as {city,dateOfBirth} and values of the attributes in another array list such as {Santa Ana, 1970-01-01}
any advice, please help!

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: you need use SAX parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create `SAXParserFactory`.
2. Create `SAXParser`.
3. Create `YourHandler`, which extends `DefaultHandler`.
4. Parse your file using `SAXParser` and `YourHandler`.

For example:

```
try {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
    parser.parse(yourFile, new YourHandler());
} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

where, `yourFile` - object of the `File` class.

In `YourHandler` class:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class YourHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String tag = "params"; // needed tag
    String city = "city"; // name of the attribute
    String value; // your value of the city

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals(tag)) {
            value = attributes.getValue(city);
        }
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}`
```

More information for SAX parser and DefaultHandler [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) and [here](http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Using JDOM (http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/):

```
    String myString = "<params city='SANTA ANA' dateOfBirth='1970-01-01'/>";
    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document myStringAsXML = builder.build(new StringReader(myString));
    Element rootElement = myStringAsXML.getRootElement();
    ArrayList<String> attributeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    attributes.addAll(rootElement.getAttributes());
    Iterator<Element> childIterator = rootElement.getDescendants();

    while (childIterator.hasNext()) {
        Element childElement = childIterator.next();
        attributes.addAll(childElement.getAttributes());
    }

    for (Attribute attribute: attributes) {
        attributeNames.add(attribute.getName());
        values.add(attribute.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("Attribute names: " + attributeNames); 
    System.out.println("Values: " + values);
```